# Simplifying LINQ Query

Tags: linq

I need a little help simplifying a LINQ query. Conditions are as follows:

- I need to apply `bool IsValid(string expression)` to every element of a given sequence.
- If `IsValid` is true for all elements, return `true`.
- If `IsValid` is false for any element, return `false`.
- If the sequence is null or empty, return `false` as well.

The query I came up with is

```
try
{
    (sequence.DefaultIfEmpty().Where(item => !IsValid(item).Count() == 0)
}
catch (ArgumentNullException)
{
    return false;
}
```

The point is that `IsValid(null)` throws an `ArgumentNullException` which is caught by the `catch` block. However, I think this is too tricky. Is there any way I can simplify the method without relyinf on this fact?

Answer (score 6):

why not:

```
return sequence.Any() && sequence.All(item => IsValid(item));
```

If you are worried about the separate `sequence.Any()` check that results in a Resharper warning (which is warranted with any sequence that you can only iterate over once like a network, DB etc.) you could write a generic extension method that does the check and iterates the sequence only once:

```
public static bool NotEmptyAndValid<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, 
                                       Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    bool hasItem = false;
    foreach(var item in source)
    {
        hasItem = true;
        if(!predicate(item))
            return false;
    }
    return hasItem;
}
```

Then you can just do:

```
return sequence.NotEmptyAndValid( x => IsValid(x));
```

Comment: Yes, you are right! However, that throws ReSharper's "Possible multiple enumeration of IEnumerable" warning, which I want to avoid.

Comment: DefaultIfEmpty will just return a null item - what's its purpose here?

Comment: yea was just fixing that part, didn't see the requirement for empty collection

Comment: @User: Added an alternative solution that only iterates the sequence once

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use:

```
return sequence.Any() && sequence.All(item => IsValid(item));
```

Comment: Yes, you are right! However, that throws ReSharper's "Possible multiple enumeration of IEnumerable" warning, which I want to avoid.

Comment: @User: In that case, to get your null/empty check in properly, a loop could be the best option...

Comment: Looks like a simul-answer to me.

Comment: @User you can ignore that warning if the sequence is in-memory. `Any()` will, at worst, look at one item in an enumeration. This is only an issue if your sequence is actually a query into a database, or something similar

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it's going to be easy to do this *nicely* with just a single pass. I'm sure it's *doable*, but I'm not sure it'd be nice. However, it's dead easy to write your own extension method:

(EDIT: I see BrokenGlass has now written a similar method with `foreach`. I'll leave this as an alternative.)

```
public static boolean AllAndNotEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source,
                                        Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    }
    if (predicate == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("predicate");
    }
    using (var iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            return false;
        }
        do
        {
            if (!predicate(iterator.Current))
            {
                return false;
            }
        } while (iterator.MoveNext());            
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then:

```
var result = items.AllAndNotEmpty(IsValid);
```